# phpinfo() shows opcache.blacklist_filename file, but contents ignored

Tags: php, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata, opcache

In my Symfony/Sonata application's `php.ini` file, I have `opcache.blacklist_filename` set to `/usr/src/app/config/opcache-exclude.txt`. In a `phpinfo()` call on my test server, that file shows up in the correct place. Here is the content of the file:

```
/usr/src/app/vendor/twig/extensions/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/SonataAdminBundle.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/TraceableAccessDecisionManager.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/*/*.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/*/*/*.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/src/CoreBundle/SonataCoreBundle.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/src/*/*.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/src/*/*/*.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/*
```

However, when I load my Sonata application, I still get this error, which is the same error that shows up when no blacklist is used:

> Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare twig_truncate_filter() (previously declared in vendor/twig/extensions/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php:38)

Am I using the wrong format in my exclusion file? How can I fix this so that the file's contents do not get ignored?

====

Update #1: When I simplify the contents of the blacklist file to this:

```
/usr/src/app/vendor/twig/extensions/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/SonataAdminBundle.php
/usr/src/app/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/TraceableAccessDecisionManager.php
```

... I still get essentially the same error:

> Compile Error: Cannot declare class Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text,
> because the name is already in use in Text.php line 15

(Yes, this is technically a different error, but it's essentially saying the same thing: The contents of Text.php are already declared in the opcache and cannot be redeclared.)

====

Update #2: Running `php -v` shows `7.4.19` as the version. Here is a bit of version info that shows up when I use `composer info`:

> twig/extra-bundle                           v3.3.1
> twig/twig                                   v2.12.2

Running `composer why twig/twig` shows this output:

```
app-insights-php/app-insights-php-bundle  0.2.5    requires  twig/twig (^1.2|^2)
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle              v2.1.2   requires  twig/twig (^1.28 || ^2.0)
sonata-project/admin-bundle               3.55.0   requires  twig/twig (^2.10)
sonata-project/block-bundle               3.18.2   requires  twig/twig (^1.34 || ^2.0)
sonata-project/core-bundle                3.17.2   requires  twig/twig (^1.34 || ^2.0)
sonata-project/formatter-bundle           4.1.3    requires  twig/twig (^2.4)
sonata-project/media-bundle               3.21.0   requires  twig/twig (^2.10)
sonata-project/page-bundle                3.13.0   requires  twig/twig (^2.10)
sonata-project/seo-bundle                 2.9.0    requires  twig/twig (^1.40 || ^2.9 || ^3.0)
sonata-project/translation-bundle         2.5.0    requires  twig/twig (^2.12)
sonata-project/user-bundle                5.x-dev  requires  twig/twig (^2.9)
symfony-cmf/routing-bundle                2.1.1    requires  twig/twig (^1.35 || ^2.4.4)
symfony/twig-bridge                       v4.4.16  requires  twig/twig (^1.41|^2.10|^3.0)
symfony/twig-bundle                       v4.4.16  requires  twig/twig (^1.41|^2.10|^3.0)
symfony/web-profiler-bundle               v4.4.16  requires  twig/twig (^1.41|^2.10|^3.0)
twig/extensions                           v1.5.4   requires  twig/twig (^1.27|^2.0)
twig/extra-bundle                         v3.3.1   requires  twig/twig (^2.4|^3.0)
```

====

Edit #3: There is no use of include_once() or require_once() in this app, beyond the normal autoloaders and configuration loaders found in many Symfony applications. This problem goes away when opcache is turned off. So it's definitely related to opcaching.

====

Edit #4: Here is my `composer.json` file.

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "name": "exozet/oesterreich-werbung-cms",
    "description": "the new cms for Österreich Werbung based on symfony with sonata",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-simplexml": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-zend-opcache": "*",
        "app-insights-php/app-insights-php-bundle": "^0.2.5",
        "app-insights-php/doctrine-dependency-logger": "^0.2.0",
        "cocur/slugify": "^3.2",
        "dracoblue/craur": "^2.1",
        "elao/enum": "^1.7",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^5.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0",
        "galbar/jsonpath": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.3.3",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "3.8.0",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "^0.6.1",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.0",
        "lightsaml/sp-bundle": "^1.2",
        "madcoda/php-youtube-api": "^1.2",
        "microsoft/azure-storage-blob": "^1.4",
        "microsoft/azure-storage-file": "^1.2",
        "microsoft/azure-storage-queue": "^1.3",
        "microsoft/azure-storage-table": "^1.1",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^4.3",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.20",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "^2.0",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.10",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^4.1",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.2",
        "sonata-project/page-bundle": "^3.12",
        "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2.5",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.4",
        "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/lock": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/messenger": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^3.3",
        "webmozart/assert": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.2",
        "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^2.5",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "ckeditor:install --clear=drop": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts",
            "/bin/sh -c \"if [ -f contrib/setup.sh ]; then contrib/setup.sh; fi\""
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

====

Edit #5:

Here is the output of `composer why twig/extensions`:

> sonata-project/admin-bundle  3.55.0  requires  twig/extensions (^1.5)
> sonata-project/core-bundle   3.17.2  requires  twig/extensions (^1.5)

Here is the content of my `preload.php` file:

```
<?php

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/dev/srcApp_KernelDevContainer.preload.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/dev/srcApp_KernelDevContainer.preload.php';
}

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevContainer.preload.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevContainer.preload.php';
}
```

... and the referenced `App_KernelDevContainer.preload.php` file contains this logic that you can see here:

https://gist.github.com/patrickmaynard/0f2cff49628fe068b989a7024cd21e34

Comment: Use you a multiple PHP versions on your server ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We only use one version of PHP on our server.

Comment: Can you please share `PHP` version and `Twig` version you're using? Also, is there any other library which is using `Twig` and having version conflict with the `Twig` version you're using?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace of the error to it and are you calling manually `include`/`require` and `include_once`/`require_once` somewhere?

Comment: If you disable OPcache, do you also get the same fatal and compile errors? And what files do redeclare the mentioned function and class and why?

Comment: Thank you, Christoph and Piemol. I have updated the question with responses to those questions. (I'm still working on getting a stack trace. None is being logged or written out to the browser by default, and I'm having trouble finding which vendor file to mess with in order to get the necessary details.)

Comment: Could you please describe the initial problem which you was trying to solve? Why did you actually decided to add files to opcache blacklist? If you return to default settings, (opcache turned on, no blacklist), what errors do you get?

Comment: Good question, Ilia. I have updated my question to show that the first error mentioned is the same whether or not a blacklist with excessive wildcards is used. (The second error, which is virtually the same, shows up when the wildcards are stripped and is now the main issue I'm trying to solve.)

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear why did you decide to exclude some files from opcache at all.

Comment: Thanks, Haridarshan. I have added the `composer.json` file. @IliaYatsenko the reason I'm blacklisting `Text.php` is that if I don't (or if I misuse wildcards), the first error shown on the question is displayed. With the file blacklisted, I'm now seeing the second error shown in the question. I hope that information helps :-)

Comment: @Patrick, and do you use a preload feature? I've found a description of similar problem https://gitmemory.com/issue/oroinc/platform/1014/653896023, but, unfortunately, without further discussion.

Anyway, the twig/extension package is abandoned https://packagist.org/packages/twig/extensions. I don't see direct dependency on it in your composer.json. Can you please show the output of `composer why twig/extension`? Just to know which packages require it.

Answer (score 1):

The errors

```
Compile Error: Cannot declare class Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text, because the name is already in use in Text.php line 15

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare twig_truncate_filter() (previously declared in vendor/twig/extensions/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Text.php:38)
```

sound a *lot* like you're having multiple declarations of same method or class *or* you're calling `include()`/`require()` multiple times explicitly or implicitly.

Do you use `include()` or `require()` *anywhere* that could be called depending on opcache being effective or not?

When you use PHP autoloader, the only explicit `include()` calls you should have are one call to load the autoloader and all the other calls in the autoloader implementation only. And make sure you don't have `include_once()` nor `require_once()` anywhere in your codebase because those do not mix well with autoloader.

The only reason to blacklist something from the opcache should be if you need to generate code that should be reloaded. It shouldn't be used to workaround code errors (e.g. incorrect `include()` chains).